# How to run maven command in AWS Device Farm

Tags: java, maven, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run my java mobile project in device farm using maven.
When I run this command on my local machine in the right directory it works:

```
 mvn test -D "cucumber.options="src/test/java/cucumber/features" --glue 
cucumber.steps --tags @InstallApp"
```

I put this command on the yaml file in the aws device farm but it doesn't work.
This is the error I get:

```
        [DeviceFarm] echo "Start Appium TestNG test"
     Start Appium TestNG test
    [DeviceFarm] mvn test -D 
    "cucumber.options="src/test/java/cucumber/features" --glue 
cucumber.steps 
    --tags @InstallApp"
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there 
     is 
     no POM in this directory (/tmp/scratchncneoU.scratch/test- 
 packageO6o8s7). 
  Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

How can I run this maven command in device farm? Where is the pom located there?

Thanks

After typing this command in the yaml file: 
[DeviceFarm] java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH -D"cucumber.options="classpath:features" --glue cucumber.steps --tags @InstallApp" org.testng.TestNG -testjar *-tests.jar -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10

I get an error of: Couldn't find the testng.xml in the jar file although I have this in my pom:

```
<directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/cucumber</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mvn` command fails because your deployment package doesn't contain the whole project. From the sound of things with the current deployment package you should be able to do what you want with this command:

`- java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH -D"cucumber.options="src/test/java/cucumber/features" --glue cucumber.steps 
--tags @InstallApp" org.testng.TestNG -testjar *-tests.jar -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10`

Otherwise, if you want to use maven you'll need to zip up the whole project and include it's `pom.xml`. So for example using the [sample cucumber java tests](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-cucumber-tests-for-sample-app)

```
git clone https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-cucumber-tests-for-sample-app.git
zip -r deployment_package.zip aws-device-farm-appium-cucumber-tests-for-sample-app
```

Then you should be able to use maven in the `testspec.yml` file. For example, I could run the following command for the sample: `mvn clean test` after going to the project dir and then to get the results I had to export the target directory.

```
  test:
    commands:
      # Your test package is downloaded in $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH so we first change directory to that path.
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/aws-device-farm-appium-cucumber-tests-for-sample-app
      - mvn clean test
...
artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/aws-device-farm-appium-cucumber-tests-for-sample-app/target
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```

However, you'll need to upload the zip file as an `APPIUM_NODE` test type to avoid the test package parser there.

HTH

-James

Comment: That is not an error, it should be a warning. You'll need to include it in the jar. Check out this support article it should help with that. 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/xml-file-tests-jar-file-device-farm/

Comment: I think I've answered that question here already actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150150/cannot-get-my-features-files-recognized-by-aws-device-farm/56202635#56202635

Comment: To put testng.xml in src/test/resources is not working in my case. Not sure why but any chance it's related to the fact that I have this in my pom:         <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/cucumber</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

Comment: Yes, if you use a test resources tag then it will override that default path in the super pom.xml so just create a new testResource tag and put in the src/test/resources path there

Comment: So you mean I should create another testResource and put it in the same testResources? So I will have 2 testResource  tags? This way they both will be included in the jar?

Comment: This is the other  testResource tag in my pom                                       
           <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/cucumber</directory>
            </testResource>

Comment: nice hack for running mvn command on AWS device farm